# SQL find rows where column is LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find rows that have a particular name on it. Problem is that some of the rows have a prefix: `"(OBSOLETE)"` or `"(OBSOLETE) "`

So for the name John, I could have three rows:

```
John
(OBSOLETE)John
(OBSOLETE) John
```

How would I write a query so that I can find all the rows that match that name knowing that sometimes a prefix will be there, and I also want those?

Comment: This can be accomplished with regular expressions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to use SQL Wildcards in a LIKE statement?

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Name LIKE '%John';
```

Answer (score 0):

To not also match BillyJohn:

```
select
  *
  from T
  where ltrim(replace(fld, '(OBSOLETE)', '')) = 'John'
```

Or simply:

```
  where fld IN ('John', '(OBSOLETE) John', '(OBSOLETE)John')
```

Which unlike the above (or `LIKE` with a lead wildcard) has a chance to use an index should one exist.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the answer. Would this work if the name was with two words, like "John Smit"? I think you are replacing the spaces.

Comment: It only replaces leading spaces not spaces between words